# Can't tell if my deck joists are treated

Tags: pressure-treated

I have a partially covered deck with tongue and groove porch boards. I want to replace them with composite decking. I can't tell if the joists are treated and would be very difficult to replace. My thoughts are to use deck joist tape then a preservative and sealer stain. Any thoughts if they are not treated will they last?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Well code is almost certainly that to use pressure-treated, but that of course doesn't mean that's what *was* used. The thing is though that even untreated softwoods can do quite well outdoors as long as they're not exposed to the full brunt of the weather which it sounds like they wouldn't be in this case; the exact species (not just pine for example, but which pine specifically) of your joists is unknown, could be a better or worse in this regard. This is a judgement-call thing, but I think you should be perfectly fine if you apply a reputable wood preservative.

Comment: The environment has a strong influence ; 10" or 50" of rain, full sun or heavy tree shade covering the deck with ( wet) leaves.

Comment: Yes as blacksmith37 says your climate type is important for predicted lifespan, but with maintenance you can extend lifespan x2, x3.

Answer (score 2):

How old is the deck and what condition are the joist in now?  That should tell you a lot about how the deck will hold up. The T&G deck should have limited the penetration of water to the structure below but, when you remove the existing deck replace any joists that are showing signs of rot.

Note that while your new composite deck will not absorb water it may allow more water to drip down in the gaps. I would recommend using a penetrating sealer on the joist framing. I would also consider placing a strips of Tyvek tape or building wrap on top of the joists to protect them before placing the decking. Don't place a continuous layer of wrap across the joists since you want any water to still drain to the ground below. However, covering the tops of the joists and hanging out a couple of inches will direct any water away from the joists and protect the tops which are most vulnerable to standing water. The area below the deck should be ventilated to avoid water condensing in the space below.